# digitalocean doctl create app returns account no access to repo

Tags: digital-ocean, digital-ocean-apps

I’m trying to create an app via doctl `doctl app create --spec .do/app.yaml` but it gives me this error

> Error: POST https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/apps: 400 (request
> “304ba4d8-b2c3-439d-8b7f-2d7f9b14a01a”) Account does not have access
> to the repo

I tried creating fresh token but no luck. I verified the doctl account I’m at via doctl auth list and verified also that the personal access token attached to auth is working as I used it to connect to digitalocean API.

Unto the Digitalocean app platform, I can browse the repo and create the app as well. Any help?